# How to write a test to test my api which returns me list of projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

I need to write a test for a list of projects are returned.

```
Scenario: Test Model method Project.all

it "Gets all projects" do 
   projects = Project.all(authentication: @auth);
   project_names = project.map {|project| project["name"]}
   expect(project_names).to match_array(["Test", "Test2", "Test3"]);
end
```

What to test against, my model method `Project.all` returns me list of `projects`, but i am not sure what to `test` against it. Right now i am checking whether the list of `project` has these titles or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the scope of the question is rather general on how and what to test.

1) A good rule of thumb is to test only what you own. That is the code that you wrote and not the framework or library methods as those are already tested. I would suggest to test custom methods and not #all method.

2) Another good rule is to realize that in the real world, you can't test all the possible branches of everything and you should test only so much to cover the most probable cases. This rule applied to the example above would mean to test only the number of objects returned and not the values of their individual attributes.

Comment: Thanks, how can we test for number of objects returned when we don't know?.